# Why is the object property returning 'undefined?'

Tags: javascript, function, return, undefined, this

Here is my code:

```
jack = {
    name: 'Jack',
    birthYear: 1992,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2021 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    }
};

console.log(jack.age);
```

Calling 'jack.age' returns 'undefined' in the console. Why is it not returning the result of the
expression in the function?

Comment: There is no property in the object called "age"

Comment: So the property 'age' can't be created using 'this' in the function?

Comment: You're not calling the `.calcAge()` method at all. If you don't call that method, the property won't be created.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Pointy you have not defined the `age` property in your object, for that you have created a function called `calcAge` if you don't call it then the property would be `undefined` which is what is returned.
If you call the `calcAge` function then `age` property would be defined and you can access it through the object.
You don't need to return age property from `calcAge` you can directly access it from the `object` if you want to recalculate the age property again then you can again call the `calcAge` function.

```js
jack = {
    name: 'Jack',
    birthYear: 1992,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2021 - this.birthYear;
    }
};
jack.calcAge();
console.log(jack.age);
```